# An elementary inequality for graph Laplacians

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be an arbitrary graph on $n$ vertices and $\mathcal L$ be its Laplacian.
I need to show that 
\begin{equation}\tag{$*$}
\langle \mathcal Lx,\mathcal L(|x|^{p-2}x)\rangle_{\mathbb R^n}\ge 0\qquad \hbox{for all }x\in \mathbb R^n
\end{equation}
and small $p\in (2,\infty)$ (my guess is that $p\approx 3$ will do), where $|x|^{p-2}x$ is the coordinatewise product (a Hadamard product, if you wish). This looks like a very simple expression, but I was unable to prove it analytically (= by methods of Calculus 1), even in the case of a graph consisting of a single edge.

(Additional information: 
I can prove by abstract nonsense that $(*)$ holds *for all* $p\in (1,\infty)$ if and only if $G$ is a complete graph; but after playing a bit with maple I can say that counterexamples seem to be extremely rare (for the path graph on 3 vertices and the vector $x=(\frac{7}{4}\pm\epsilon,1,-1)$, $(*)$ fails for all $p\ge 6$ and very small $\epsilon$, though).)

Any help is appreciated.

---

Update: as pointed out in the comments, the case of a one-edge-graph *is* actually trivial.

Comment: For a graph with one edge this means just that $|x|^{p-2}x$ is an increasing function, no?

Comment: Well, for a graph with one edge the inequality is $(x-y)(|x|^{p-2}x-|y|^{p-2}y)\ge 0$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$, so yes, you're right, I was overlooking this and all I am claiming is that $|x|^{p-2}x$ is an increasing function. So that's proved. But this does not carry over to the general case, as my example shows.

Comment: May small $p$ depend on our graph?

Comment: Yes, it may well. As I said, I can prove that the infimal $p$ for which $(*)$ fails blows up if and only if $G$ is complete.

Comment: Obviously, if you take the star with the center of large degree $d$, the inequality can be violated for all $p>p(d)\to 2$ as $d\to\infty$ (only the center really matters because the Laplacian there is of size $d$ while everywhere else it is of size $1$ and $d$ ones lose to one $d^2$). So there is no way you can get a universal notion of "smallness", i.e., $\approx 3$ is too optimistic. Let's see if $2<p<p(G)$ with some $p(G)>2$ is a feasible range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2<p<p(G)$ with $p(G)>2$ is, indeed, possible. Moreover, it is Analysis 1. Calculus 1 is an extremely difficult subject, never try to learn it yourself or to explain it to your students. It is way above a normal person's head! (It is second in difficulty only to Business Calculus, which is just beyond the comprehension of any human being). Analysis 1, on the other hand, can be explained to a 10-year old.

Let's normalize somehow. Since Laplacian is related to the gradient squared, assume that $\sum_{x\sim y}|f(x)-f(y)|^2=1$. Then the oscillation of $f$ is bounded by some $C(G)$. We also have our beautiful relation $\sum_x (f(x)-F)\mathcal Lf(x)=\sum_{x\sim y}|f(x)-f(y)|^2=1$ for any $F\in\mathbb R$ (or $-1$ depending on what you subtract from what in the definition of $\mathcal L$). Subtracting the median, we get $|f-F|\le C(G)$, so, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$\sigma(f)=\sum_x(\mathcal Lf(x))^2\ge c(G)$. Now, assume that the median $F$ of $f$ is in some moderate range $[-A,A]$. Then we have $y|y|^\alpha\to y$ uniformly on $[-A-C(G),A+C(G)]$ as $\alpha=p-2\to 0+$ and your expression tends to $\sigma(f)\ge c(G)$ uniformly over $f$ with values in that range. So for each $A$, you are fine with $\alpha<\alpha_0(A,G)\in(0,1)$. It remains to investigate what happens if $F$ is huge. Then your function can be written as $F+g$, $|g|\le C(G)\ll F$, so (assuming that $F>0$, the other case is similar)
$$
|f(x)|^\alpha f(x)-|f(y)|^\alpha f(y)=F^{1+\alpha}(1+g(x)/F)^{1+\alpha}-(1+g(y)/F)^{1+\alpha}\\
=F^{1+\alpha}[(1+\alpha)(g(x)-g(y))/F+O(|g(x)-g(y)|(|g(x)|+|g(y)|)/F^2)
=(1+\alpha)F^\alpha(g(x)-g(y))+O(|g(x)-g(y)|(|g(x)|+|g(y)|)/F^{1-\alpha})
$$ 
This means that $F^{-\alpha}(\mathcal L|f|^\alpha f)(x)$ uniformly tends to $(1+\alpha)\mathcal Lf(x)$ as $F\to\infty$, so the expression you are interested in is asymptotic to $(1+\alpha)F^\alpha \sigma(f)$ for large $F$ with any $\alpha\in(0,1)$, say. Thus there exists $A$ such that for all $|F|>A$ you have positivity in the range $0<\alpha<1$. Take this $A$ and put $p(G)=2+\alpha(A,G)$.

Of course, you can try to get more precise result here, but my point was that the question is a no-brainer for anybody who just recognized once in his life that he has no hope to master the high art of Calculus and confined himself to the low craft of Analysis instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very right about the advantages of Analysis (and all the more so of Russian Analysis) over Calculus.

That said, when I was estimating $p\approx 3$ I was actually being _pessimistic_: what you've just proved is that the exponential matrix generated by (minus) the discrete bi-Laplacian is always contractive wrt $p$-norm, and  the set of such $p$'s can get arbitrarily large, which is in my eyes says that a certain ODE is well-behaved.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to quote this proof in a paper. Is there any specific way you'd like to be mentioned? Feel free to send me a private mail if you wish, my home page is in my profile.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo You are welcome! As to Calculus vs Analysis, when you are at the board in the classroom *you* are the only one to choose which one to teach (if you are above the level when students' squeaks can damage your position in any way). As to quoting, just cite MO. There are instructions somewhere (I have never learned where exactly) on the MO web page about how to do it most properly, but I guess that if you just use your common sense, that will work too. As to "large range of $p$", yes, it can get large, but it can get small as well. Depends on the graph structure.

Comment: By the way: is there a special reason you use the median instead of the mean value?

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Not really. Anything from $\min$ to $\max$ will work nicely. It was just the first "m"-word that came to my head. That's it :-)

Comment: One more thing: you write "it can get large, but it can get small as well. Depends on the graph structure." Right, that's what I believe as well. And your example with stars shows that $p$ may actually blow up. However, your proof yields that my expression is certainly positive for $p$ close enough to 2, but does not exclude the possibility that even the "worse" graphs have much larger $p$, I'd say. So, it's still open whether there exist graphs such that my inequality is never satisfied for $p=3$.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo What do you mean? If we take *any* $p_0>2$, there exists $d=d(p_0)$ such that on the $d$-star the inequality fails in general for all $p>p_0$. So just take $d=d(5/2)$ and $p=3$ is out of question. Of course, it may still hold with any $p$ for some carefully chosen functions, but this is not what you are after, is it?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I had completely misunderstood/misread your comment about stars.